# Andriod Studio:E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android

please solve this issue I am a beginner in android development I don't know what the issue is.

> Process: com.example.myapplicationofexarth, PID: 2703
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplicationofexarth/com.example.myapplicationofexarth.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to
> android.widget.TextView at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) Caused
> by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
> android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to
> android.widget.TextView at
> com.example.myapplicationofexarth.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.myapplicationofexarth;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textexample);
        text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `layout/activity_main`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the error message I'd say you've probably given the R.Id.textexample to the constraint layout instead of the TextView  by accident.

check the Id of the textView in the xml layout.